# B-Tree- method inorder(TreeNode<E> root)

Tags: java

I don't understand this method.

```
 protected void inorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
  if (root == null) return;
   inorder(root.left);
   System.out.print(root.element + " ");
   inorder(root.right);
}
```

When `current node` comes to last node in the tree and current.left become null, what then happened?  `current node` returns where? When that node is going to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `root.left` is null, the function call `inorder(root.left);` will do nothing but return immediatley and then you will continue on with root and its right subtree.